# What part of speech is "as" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Rachel described Miami **as** a beautiful city.

I'm finding it hard to determine whether "as" is used as an adverb, preposition, or pronoun. I need your view on this.

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, "as" is a preposition.
The prepositional phrase "as a beautiful city" is the complement of the prepositional verb "describe ... as ...".
The object of the preposition "as" is the noun phrase "a beautiful city".
The usage is similar to "see x as y", "regard x as y", or "count x as y".

The use is called "predicative" since it ascribes a property to Miami.